# Realm not writing because already performing write operation

Tags: java, android, realm

I am trying to update my recycler view such that when the plus button on one of its items is clicked a the quantity text view on that item is incremented by 1.

Here is the code for the click listener in the adapter.

```
holder.mQuantityPlusTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mEventBus.post(new CartQuantityPlusClickEvent(imgUrl));
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

Here is the code for the activity subscribing to the EventBus.

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.POSTING)
public void cartQuantityPlusClick(CartQuantityPlusClickEvent event) {
    mClothingRepository.plusClothingCartQuantity(event.getImgUrl());
}
```

Here is the code for the actual quantity update.

```
@Override
public void plusClothingCartQuantity(String imgUrl) {
    CartItem item = mRealm.where(CartItem.class).equalTo("imgUrl", imgUrl).findFirst();

    mRealm.beginTransaction();

    if (item != null)
        item.increasQuantity(); Log.d(TAG, item.getQuantityInCart() + "");

    mRealm.commitTransaction();
}
```

When I run the app and press the button. No change in quantity occurs, despite the exact same code as for decreasing the quantity which works.

Here is the code for decreasing the quantity (the code for the adapter and event bus is virtually the same).

```
@Override
public void minusClothingCartQuantity(String imgUrl) {
    CartItem item = mRealm.where(CartItem.class).equalTo("imgUrl", imgUrl).findFirst();
    mRealm.beginTransaction();

    if (item != null) {
        if (item.getQuantityInCart() == DEFAULT_CART_ITEM_QUANTITY) {
            item.deleteFromRealm();
        } else
            item.decreaseQuantity();
    }

    RealmResults<CartItem> cartItems = mRealm.where(CartItem.class).findAll();
    if (cartItems.size() == 0)
        mEventBus.post(new EmptyCartEvent());

    mRealm.commitTransaction();
}
```

The log statement in the code for incrementing the quantity says that the `item` variable is null and that:

```
12-29 12:25:31.881 21538-21538/com.geteven.gooddeal E/REALM_JNI: jni: ThrowingException 8, The Realm is already in a write transaction in /Users/cm/Realm/realm-java-release/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_OsSharedRealm.cpp line 126, .
12-29 12:25:31.882 21538-21538/com.geteven.gooddeal E/REALM_JNI: Exception has been thrown: The Realm is already in a write transaction in /Users/cm/Realm/realm-java-release/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_OsSharedRealm.cpp line 126
12-29 12:25:31.884 21538-21538/com.geteven.gooddeal E/EventBus: Could not dispatch event: class com.geteven.gooddeal.event.CartQuantityPlusClickEvent to subscribing class class com.geteven.gooddeal.view.CartActivity
                                                                java.lang.IllegalStateException: The Realm is already in a write transaction in /Users/cm/Realm/realm-java-release/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_OsSharedRealm.cpp line 126
                                                                    at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.nativeBeginTransaction(Native Method)
                                                                    at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.beginTransaction(OsSharedRealm.java:282)
                                                                    at io.realm.BaseRealm.beginTransaction(BaseRealm.java:389)
                                                                    at io.realm.Realm.beginTransaction(Realm.java:135)
                                                                    at com.geteven.gooddeal.repository.ClothingRepository.plusClothingCartQuantity(ClothingRepository.java:145)
                                                                    at com.geteven.gooddeal.view.CartActivity.cartQuantityPlusClick(CartActivity.java:190)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.invokeSubscriber(EventBus.java:485)
                                                                    at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.postToSubscription(EventBus.java:416)
                                                                    at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.postSingleEventForEventType(EventBus.java:397)
                                                                    at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.postSingleEvent(EventBus.java:370)
                                                                    at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:251)
                                                                    at com.geteven.gooddeal.adapter.CartAdapter$3.onClick(CartAdapter.java:122)
                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6289)
                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24800)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6809)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

I get my realm instance from the constructor of the repository class where all business logic is contained.

```
public ClothingRepository() {
    mEventBus = EventBus.getDefault();
    mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    mClothingRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child(FIREBASE_CLOTHING_REFERENCE);
}
```

I don't close it because I'm not sure how to. I feel this may be part of the problem. How do I fix this?

Comment: *I'm not sure how to* - call `mRealm.close()`

Comment: Yes but if I call `mRealm.close()` can I still use it later?

Comment: no. Read the docs

Comment: So then how would I close it?

Comment: Please see my answer below, I hope it is what you need

Answer (score 0):

You should always get instance of realm before using it. And close the instance after using.

```
@Override
public void plusClothingCartQuantity(String imgUrl) {
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    CartItem item = realm.where(CartItem.class).equalTo("imgUrl", imgUrl).findFirst();

    realm.beginTransaction();

    if (item != null)
        item.increasQuantity(); Log.d(TAG, item.getQuantityInCart() + "");

    realm.commitTransaction();
    realm.close()
}
```

See my code of function, that you should use. First you should not use mRealm field and call `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` every time when you want any DB operation.
After using, don't forget to call `realm.close()`

Comment: Please do like this https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/4217#issuecomment-281507165 otherwise you may run into this issue https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3753#issuecomment-258858231